# how to get values from bootstrap input-tags and then insert into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I used bootstrap input-tags in my site. but I can't just handle the tags' values as they are rendered in a span tag with the same class names. I want to get values of each rendered tag and then insert into MySQL database using php and jQuery. what I have for now is:

```
<head>
<!-- botstrap-tags css and js -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-tags/css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" type="text/css">
<script src="bootstrap-tags/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
</head>

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Tags</label>
<input type="text" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" value="sport, politics, business">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" value="add tags">
</div>
</form>
```

when I'm done with adding my tags, it generates tags as:

```
<span class="tag label label-info">
"sport" 
<span data-role="remove">
::after
</span>
</span>
<span class="tag label label-info">
"poltics" 
<span data-role="remove">
::after
</span>
</span>
<span class="tag label label-info">
"business" 
<span data-role="remove">
::after
</span>
</span>
```

this is my php script

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'web';
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $link ) {
echo 'Connected failure<br>';
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$tags=$_POST['tags'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tags`(`name`) VALUES ('$tags')";
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
// alert success message
echo "tags added successfully";
}
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}
}
?>
```

anyone can help? thanks

Comment: So when you submit form - what is there in `$_POST`?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/de/tutorial.forms.php for your form and at http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php or https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp for your database connection.

Comment: You can also have a look https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm a little confused as to what you want, but I will try to answer based on the information as I understood it.**

> jQuery is required for my answer.
>
> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Create the HTML form with the `POST` method to send the data to the PHP file.

```
<form action="your_file.php" method="POST">
    <input name="tag" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

In your PHP file, using the `$_POST[]` superglobal, get the input data.

```
$tagValue = $_POST['tag'];
```

Finally, create the SQL command and query the database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table('name') VALUES('$tagValue')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$result)
{
    echo('failure');
} else {
    echo('success');
}
```

---

EDIT: I believe I understand the question now.

To get the data of dynamically generated content, you will most likely have to use Javascript.

```
var $elements = $('.tag');
var elementValues = {};

for (var i = 0; i < $elements; i++)
{
    elementValues[i] = $elements[i].text();
}

var sendableData = JSON.stringify(elementValues);

$.post('your_file.php' { data: sendableData }, function () {
    console.log('data sent');
});
```

The Javascript will send the data to the PHP file in JSON format. The PHP needs to decode the JSON, and return that data into a PHP object.

```
$jsonData = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($jsonData);

foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table('name') VALUES('$value')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Comment: one thing you don't understand is, I am using bootstrap tags-input library to add my tags the line "<input type="text" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" value="sport, politics, business">" " data-role="tagsinput"" have something to do with my tags, i.e. it makes the library to generate my tags formated a better way like in this sites's tags

Comment: @MehammedbrhanAbdelkadr Please view my updated answer.

Comment: I think you got me, I hope that can help me. thanks bro

Comment: @MehammedbrhanAbdelkadr No problem. If my answer is correct, please check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must make the input to accept array :

```
<input type="text" name="tags[]" data-role="tagsinput" value="sport, politics, business">
```

in your php :

```
$tags  = $_POST['tags'];
$tags  = json_encode($tags); 
$tags  = htmlspecialchars_decode($tags); // save this to database
```

you will get : ["sport, politics, business"] save in database. Extract this value if you want to retreive.